# Controller is not getting file submitted

Tags: forms, file, laravel-5.1

i am submitting the form which is having file but when i try to get the file in  controller it always return failure.

i have tried possible thing.

Save

public function storeLogo(request $request){

```
if($request->hasFile('logo')){

         $image=$request->file($yes);
         $fileName= time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $location=public_path('merchantGlobal/'.$fileName);
         Image::make($image)->save($location);
         return "success";

  }

        return "failure";


}
```

I want get success message of controller

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Are you sure that the upload was successful? Of which type is that `$request` variable?

Comment: when i submit the form the file name shows up in the url ...

what is your suggestion? what i should try?

Comment: Well, you should start to debug the problem :) The best thing would be to start up XDebug to inspect the `$request` object

Comment: public function storeLogo(Request $request){
here is the function definition